# Guardar un Usuario MVC c#, SQL

Tags: c#, sql, mvc, http-post

soy prestador de servicio social y soy principiante en MVC,  estoy haciendo un vista donde en la parte superior tengo 3 DropDownList y un botón de guardar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero hacer es que guarde el Usuario y me regrese a la misma vista `Index`. Al guardar lo hace con dos diferentes `SP's` que afectan a dos diferentes Tablas en `SQL`.

Esta es la parte de mi `Index` que lo hace:

```
div id="contenedor-form-crear">
<form id="formEditar" method="post" class="documento-cargar" data-container="contenedor-form-crear" data-url= "@Url.Action("Guardar", "Seguridad")";>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <label class="control-label ">Usuario</label>
                <select id="ArchivoEjercicioGlobal" class="form-control" asp-for="@Model.NOMBRE" asp-items="@ViewBag.vwbUsuario" OnChange="SetCCDI">
                    <option value="">- Seleccione -</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <label class="control-label ">CCDI</label>
                <select id="ArchivoFraccionGlobal" class="form-control" asp-for="@Model.CCDI" asp-items="@ViewBag.vwbCcdi">
                    <option value="">- Seleccione -</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <label class="control-label ">Rol</label>
                <select id="ArchivoFraccionGlobal" class="form-control" asp-for="@Model.ROLES" asp-items="@ViewBag.vwbRoles">
                    <option value="">- Seleccione -</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <br />
            <div class="form-group pull-right">
                <div>

                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <button type="submit" id="BtnGuardar" value="Guardar" class="btn btn-primary">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk" aria-hidden="true"></span>&nbsp;Guardar&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</button>
                </div>
            </div>


        </div>
    </div>

</form>
```

Este la acción Guardar de mi controlador, mando a llamar los dos métodos que guardan en las diferentes tablas.

```
   [HttpPost]

    public ActionResult Guardar(TablaUsuario tUsuario)
    {
        _objRNSeguridad.AsignarCCDIUsuario(tUsuario.ID_USUARIO, tUsuario.ID_CCDI);
       _objRNSeguridad.AsignarRolUsuario(tUsuario.ID_USUARIO, tUsuario.ROLE_INT, true);


        return RedirectToAction("Guardar","Index");
    }
```

Entonces cuando doy clic en guardar trata de realizar la acción pero me marca que no puedo acceder y no guarda nada. Alguien sabrá decirme que podría ser?¡

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: podris ser mas claro cuando dice "me marca que no puedo acceder ", que seria especificamente? obtienes algun exception, si es asi que dice el mensaje?

Comment: Ninguna exception, solo no encuentra la página

Comment: si pones un breakpoint en el action Guardar() no se detiene la ejecucion? no ingresa, porque puede que el submit no resuelva la url o puede que sea el RedirectToAction

Comment: Estas llegando al guardar? estara mal la ruta? fijate en el navegador,en la consola de desarrollo (apretando f12 en firefox por ejemplo) a donde hace la llamada al apretar el boton.

Comment: @LeandroTuttini no, no se detiene la ejecución,

Comment: inspecciona con el developer tools el html y valida que url esta definiendo en el tag <form>, porque en la imagen menciona Seguridad que seria el controller peor no define el action, algo estaria incorrecto en data-url

Answer (score 0):

Si realizas el submit del form los tag html `select` no tienen definido el `name` coindidente con las propiedades de la clase `TablaUsuario` por lo tanto no podrias recibir la seleccion que realizo el usuario.

Se supone que la view le debe llegar un model que tenga la propiedad `ID_USUARIO` para definir

```
<select id="ArchivoEjercicioGlobal" class="form-control" asp-for="ID_USUARIO" asp-items="@ViewBag.vwbUsuario" OnChange="SetCCDI">
```

valida como se debe indicar `asp-for="ID_USUARIO"`

No veo porque defines `asp-for="@Model.NOMBRE"`, eso es incorrecto

[ASP.NET Core MVC Input Tag Helper Deep Dive](https://www.davepaquette.com/archive/2015/05/13/mvc6-input-tag-helper-deep-dive.aspx)

lo que tienes que asegurar es que el `tag html` tenga la propiedad `name` coincidente con la propiedad de la class que defines en el parametro del action (en tu caso una propiedad de `TablaUsuario`), sino al realizar el submit no recibiras la seleccion, ya que model binding de asp.net mvc no sabra donde mapear el valor que le llega

Valida esto mismo para los demas combos